# Mirroring to multiple android devices

Tags: screen-mirroring

Is there any way I can mirror one android device to other Android devices in my local network?

Answer (score 1):

Try screen **streaming over HTTP**, for that you can use an open-source [Screen Stream](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/info.dvkr.screenstream/) application available on F-droid.The application allows viewing the device screen in your web browser.

> It uses MJPEG to encode screen images and send them through the
>   network. So it works with any desktop or mobile browser which supports
>   MJPEG (Chrome, Safari, EDGE, Firefox).

Depending on what you are trying to achieve, it is best suited  to show your device screen during presentations and demos but not ideal for streaming video, and does not even support sound (since MJPEG does not support sound).

> Expected delay is at least 0.5-1 second or more on slow devices, bad
>   WiFi or on heavy CPU load by other apps.

The application works via **Wi-Fi** (and/or 3G/LTE network). Fast and stable Wi-Fi recommended because of high traffic and low network delay requirement. **No Internet required**, however, there must be a network connection between the client and the device.

The number of client connections is **unlimited**, but be aware that each of them requires some CPU resources and bandwidth to send data.

*Note:  Some Wi-Fi networks (mostly public/guest) block connections between its clients for security reasons, so you may not be able to connect to the device via Wi-Fi  cell operators may block incoming connections to your device for security reasons, so you may not be able to connect to the device on using this IP address.*